# Avoid having infinite loops

Tags: multisite, user-roles

I am using the following code (https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/set_user_role/) to sync user role between his blogs on a multisite installation.

My question is if this approach can lead to an infinite loop?

```
// Sync user role
add_action( 'set_user_role', 'sync_user_role', 10, 2 );
function sync_user_role( $user_id, $role ) {

    $blogs = get_blogs_of_user( $user_id );

    $blogs_count = count( $blogs );

    if ( $blogs_count > 1 ) {
        foreach ( $blogs as $blog ) {

            $user_blog = new WP_User( $user_id, '', $blog->userblog_id );

            $user_blog->set_role( $role );
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it will give you infinite loop, because you're calling the `WP_User::set_role` method within the `set_user_role` action that's again fired within the the `WP_User::set_role` method.

Not sure what the setup is but you can try to run it only once, with

```
remove_action( current_action(), __FUNCTION__ );
```

as the first line in your callback, or use another hook.

*Update: I just noticed that I miswrote `filter` instead of `action`, but that would have worked the same though ;-) It's now adjusted.*

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove the filter before you set the rule. See code example below:

```
// Sync user role
add_action( 'set_user_role', 'sync_user_role', 10, 2 );
function sync_user_role( $user_id, $role ) {

    $blogs = get_blogs_of_user( $user_id );

    $blogs_count = count( $blogs );

    if ( $blogs_count > 1 ) {
        foreach ( $blogs as $blog ) {

            $user_blog = new WP_User( $user_id, '', $blog->userblog_id );
            remove_action( 'set_user_role', 'sync_user_role', 10);
            $user_blog->set_role( $role );
            add_action( 'set_user_role', 'sync_user_role', 10, 2 );
        }
    }
}
```